# ASP.NET MVC Calling multiple PartialView instances for multiple views with inherited models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two (or more) views which share the same basis but are slightly different ie. an additional table. This would be a great opportunity to use PartialView, to remove duplicate code. Unfortunately, in the case of a model that I would use to solve the inheritance is a problem.

How do I tell PartialView, which View (with which model) is calling it?

I do not want to send enumerate in ViewBag, which would than be used for switching without changing type, because I can't use PartialView without changing type as some of the dynamic models do not accept some helper components.

ParentFacade.cs

```
public class ParentFacade
{
    public Container Charts{ get; set; }
    public DashboardModel DashboardModel{ get; set; }
    public List<TimeValuePriority> ATimeValueList{ get; set; }
    public string UnitsOfVal1 { get; set; }
}
```

ChildFacade.cs

```
public class ChildFacade : ParentFacade
{
    public List<TimeMeasuredValue> BTimeValueList{ get; set; }
    public string UnitsOfVal2 { get; set; }
}
```

_FirstPartial.cshtml

```
@model  ???
@{int lenght = 0;}
        <div>
            <table class="my-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">@String.Format("{0} [{1}/{2}]", Resource.Activity, Resource.Unit, Model.UnitsOfVal1 )</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{lenght = Model.ATimeValueList.Count; }
                    @if (lenght == 0)
                    {
                        <tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr>}
                    @for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                    {
                        if (Model.DashboardModel.Interval == IntervalEnum.Week)
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                <tr><td colspan="2">@Model.ATimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("d")</td></tr>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Model.ATimeValueList[i - 1].Time.Date != Model.ATimeValueList[i].Time.Date)
                                {
                                    <tr><td colspan="2">@Model.ATimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("d")</td></tr>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        <tr>
                            <td class="number">
                                @if (Model.DashboardModel.Interval == IntervalEnum.Month)
                                {
                                    @Model.ATimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("d")
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @Model.ATimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("t")
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="number">@Model.ATimeValueList[i].Value</td>
                        </tr>}
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
```

_SecondPartial.cshtml

```
@model  ???
@{int lenght = 0;}
 <div>
        <table class="My-tables">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @if (Model.DashboardModel.Interval != IntervalEnum.Month)
                    {
                        <th colspan="2">@String.Format("{0} [{1}]", Resource.Val2, Model.UnitsOfVal2)</th>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <th colspan="2">@String.Format("{0} {1} [{2}]", Resource.SumaPerDay, Resource.Val2, Model.UnitsOfVal2)</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{lenght = Model.BTimeValueList.Count; }
                @if (lenght == 0)
                {
                    <tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr>}
                @for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                {

                    switch (Model.DashboardModel.Interval)
                    {
                        case IntervalEnum.Day:
                            <tr>
                                <td class="number">
                                    @Model.BTimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("t")
                                </td>
                                <td class="number">@String.Format("{0:f1}", @Model.BTimeValueList[i].Amount)</td>
                            </tr>break;
                        case IntervalEnum.Week:
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                <tr><td colspan="2">@Model.BTimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("d")</td></tr>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Model.BTimeValueList[i - 1].Time.Date != Model.BTimeValueList[i].Time.Date)
                                {
                                    <tr><td colspan="2">@Model.BTimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("d")</td></tr>
                                }
                            }
                            <tr>
                                <td class="number">
                                    @Model.BTimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("t")
                                </td>
                                <td class="number">@String.Format("{0:f1}", @Model.BTimeValueList[i].Amount)</td>
                            </tr>break;
                        case IntervalEnum.Month:
                            <tr><td>@Model.BTimeValueList[i].Time.ToString("d")</td><td class="number">@String.Format("{0:f1}", @Model.BTimeValueList[i].Amount)</td></tr>break;
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

AView.cshtml

```
@model Web.ControllersFacade.ParentFacade
 <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DashboardModel.StartDate.Date, new { @id = "startDateId" })

        <div class="row top-menu" id="top-menu">
            @Html.Partial("SharedPartials/_IntervalMenuPartial",Model.DashboardModel)
        </div>
        <div class="row row-eq-height no-margin">
            <div id="work-place" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                <div id="graphs" class="graphs">
                    @(Model.Charts)
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="btn-link left-button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
                        @Html.ActionLink(Resource.ExportCSV, "DownloadFile", "FileTransport", new { id = Model.DashboardModel.SelectedClientIds }, new { })
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div id="table">
                    @Html.Partial("SharedPartials/_FirstPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

BView.cshtml

```
@model Web.ControllersFacade.ChildFacade
 <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DashboardModel.StartDate.Date, new { @id = "startDateId" })

        <div class="row top-menu" id="top-menu">
            @Html.Partial("SharedPartials/_IntervalMenuPartial",Model.DashboardModel)
        </div>
        <div class="row row-eq-height no-margin">
            <div id="work-place" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                <div id="graphs" class="graphs">
                    @(Model.Charts)
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="btn-link left-button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
                        @Html.ActionLink(Resource.ExportCSV, "DownloadFile", "FileTransport", new { id = Model.DashboardModel.SelectedClientIds }, new { })
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div id="table">
                    @Html.Partial("SharedPartials/_FirstPartial")
                    @Html.Partial("SharedPartials/_SecondPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can create a ViewModel that contains these 2 classes as Properties and send it to the PartialView. For exmaple: public class ViewModel{ public ParentFacade ParentFacade{get; set;} public ChildFacade ChildFacade{get; set;} }. and then send this ViewModel class as Model to the partial view

Comment: @alaa_sayegh This way is in my oppinion stupid. Why we have OOP?

Comment: and what do you think is a good practise, use Model or ViewModels in MVC Views? And if you say ViewModels, can you tell me then why? And also why you think this is aginst OOP?

Comment: @alaa_sayegh In my oppinion it is agaist OOP because I send too much. Maybe I am wrong and my prefered solution are not best practice.

Comment: @alaa_sayegh I think sending data to View as big as this is nonsense throw ViewData (e.g). But sending with Model is not ideal two. It is for sending data back (from client).
Your solution leads to make only "parent" with everything and that is a my old solution and I want new better solution because old solution is not ideal.

Comment: there are of course many ways to work around such a case. But I would prefer always to work with ViewModels for the views. Your Models are something related to the BLL and there you have your inheritance and dependencies. Of course you will have it also in the frontend, but give the frontend excatly what it needs no more no less. With my suggestion you are combining the two dependent models in one and giving to view, what is wrong with that? you can even use it to send data back from client and at controller level you can split them. Anyway, it is just a suggestion from my side

Comment: @alaa_sayegh back to your original question. Why I do not use ViewModel with 2 classes? I am on the start again. How to say simply PartialView "now use parent, now use child" without many conditions _if is it null_ (or something else).
Maybe there are not another way that make one _monster_ Model (ViewModel) for all Views.

Comment: A View has a defined model class, you cannot tell the view, now use this and in the next request with this other model. If you wanna use both dynamically you need to achieve an object that contains both and give it to the view which will detect itself through if/else conditons (lot of work :( ), which one is null and which one to use. Maybe you can set a flag (bool property) which says now i'm parent and now i'm child. :)

Comment: @alaa_sayegh yeah but I want avoid _flag_. Flag make more code (conditions) and I am on start again.
I tried It resolve by declaration with `switch` but declaration of _@model_ can be one time in View.

Comment: Of course it is onetime in the View. Thats exactly what im trying to tell :)

Comment: @alaa_sayegh Yeah I know, but I want something like casting child to parent. Because I know in View It is Child or Parent and i want send info to PartialView who is it.